# Totally Confused with jasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, salesforce, ireport

I am new to jasper only 2 days before I started. I download jasperReports and iReports. And installed iReports and installed jasper4salesforce in my salesforce account but not find any setup with jasperReports. How to use it I am totally confused I am not getting any idea to use it can you please help me to find the solution. I am trying to connect jasper to salesforce.

Comment: Where did you get a Jasper4Salesforce from? It was discontinued 3 years ago.

Comment: I get it from 
http://appexchange.salesforce.com/reviews?listingId=a0N300000016a5DEAQ&filter=1
Can you help me to solve my problem.

Comment: You installed the thing called "Jasper4Salesforce - DISCONTINUED". You will perhaps not be surprised to learn that the product was... discontinued.

Comment: But it got installed and i got information from a old site 2006. Ok can i get connected to salesforce using jasper.

Comment: Hello is their any way for connection. I am open to any kind of connection. If possible please help me.

Answer (score 1):

With the removal of Jasper4Salesforce I don't think there is a simple integration, but I would imagine you could either export the data from SFDC into a csv for use in Jasper.

The real question is why do you need to use Jasper with SFDC having a built in reporting tool?

EDIT:

The following is a Crystal Reports SFDC integration http://crystalreports.com/salesforce/default.asp

Comment: Thanks for your replay. This is only a research on better reporting engine than the salesforce offering. If their is no direct way of connection to salesforce to jasper can you suggest any other reporting engine for saleforce connection.

Comment: Try the Crystal Reports integration. Still surprised you have a report that you cannot fashion on SFDC, most of the time it is easily doable. Will edit the answer to link to the Crystal integration.